# Website not running

Tags: magento-1.4

web site is not running both frontend and backend! After cleaning all log tables (like log_visitor, log_customer...) in phpMyAdmin, DB size was reduced from 1.3Gb to 26M! I have old magento version 1.4.1! Please help!
Error in var\report directory:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:138:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user 'pythongrip'@'182.50.130.52' for table 'log_visitor'";i:1;s:2557:"#0 /home/content/80/7043280/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/content/80/7043280/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home/content/80/7043280/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#3 /home/content/80/7043280/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/content/80/7043280/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(546): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(414): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)
#6 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#7 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(149): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#8 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1228): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1209): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#11 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(497): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(59): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#13 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noCookies')
#15 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/content/80/7043280/html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/content/80/7043280/html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}";s:3:"url";s:209:"/index.php/catalog/product_compare/add/product/134/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5weXRob25ncmlwLmNvbS9pbmRleC5waHAvY2F0YWxvZ3NlYXJjaC9yZXN1bHQvaW5kZXgvP19fX1NJRD1VJmRpcj1kZXNjJm1vZGU9bGlzdCZvcmRlcj1yZWxldmFuY2UmcT0xMjU,/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}


a:4:{i:0;s:95:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'pythongrip.db.7043280.hostedresource.com' (0)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities :

**1/** You need to grant the `INSERT` privilege to your user `pythongrip` in MySQL
source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10956306/3531064

**2/** your have the wrong prefix to your database tables
source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27463050/3531064

Answer (score 0):

1/ Check you **app/etc/local.xml** DB connection settings

2/ Test those settings in a testdb.php file

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

3/ Clear your Magento cache (var/cache/*)